# Setting the fill of a rectangle drawn with canvas to an RGB value

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
w.create_rectangle(x, y, s, s, fill=(109,170,44))
```

I want to achieve something like this, but when I try it I get an error. I'm creating several rectangles using an array / list and I want them to be this shade of green, but can't seem to find a way that works. So far the only thing that has worked is

```
w.create_rectangle(x, y, s, s, fill="green")
```

But it's not the shade I want. Any help is greatly appreciated, and I feel although I'm missing something big and really easy here, but I've been hung up on this problem for awhile now.

Comment: Also use `outline=` to choose the outline color.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting an "unknown color name" error. You have to either use the name from the [list of colors](http://wiki.tcl.tk/37701) or use hexadecimal format: #RRGGBB

To convert a tuple of integer values to RGB format use this:

```
colorval = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (109, 170, 44)
```

This will result in *#6daa2c*